# At what point are options not "significant"?

Tags: statistical-significance, data-visualization

For example, say there's a survey question with 500 possible answers (this isn't actually the case - it's not a survey, and there are far more than 500 options), and I want to display people's responses. I'm looking for a way to decide when to stop displaying data individually, and to instead lump everything together as "Other" (as in, these options didn't receive a significant number of votes). At what point do I say "this is the last one that I want to display individually, everything with less votes than this one is categorized as Other"?

One idea I have now is to create subsets of options (starting with only the most popular) and, for each subset, calculate the [Herfindahl Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herfindahl_index). When adding the next most popular option doesn't change the index significantly (say, by 0.01), that and any less popular options get lumped into "Other".

I understand this is an subjective issue, but I was wondering if there are any existing statistical models or popular methods for this type of problem. I'm also not a statistician, so apologies if I just don't know the name for this problem and a simple Google would have told me the answer.

Comment: This is more of a subject matter concern than a statistical one, I think. You should probably try to figure out at what point would you or a viewer of your display no longer care about the additional, smaller options.

Comment: @Glen_b, you're absolutely correct - I made a mistake, and meant subjective there. I was mostly wondering if there's some system or algorithm in common practice used to decide this sort of thing.

Comment: *"I want to display people's responses."* This seems incredibly difficult when you have more than 500 types of responses. Can't you do something about your survey that makes it more restricted or allows you to get a smaller amounts of categories? What sort of 'options' do you actually have, how do you get to more than 500? Is it like sentences/text and you want to categorise those or is is like a multidimensional vector of smaller options that multiplies to a multitude of combinations? It is a bit unclear what your survey is and what you are asking the statistics community here.